# How detect ip and port on lan and display in list view from same application

Tags: vb.net, client-server

how detect ip and port from same application and display to list view?

This is the code that I use and application I install to multiple computers.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net

Public Class frmutama
    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim rnres = (rn.Next(8000, 8888))
    Dim listener As New TcpListener(rn.Next(8000, 8888))
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim message As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim hostname As String = Dns.GetHostName()
        Dim ipaddress As String = CType(Dns.GetHostByName(hostname).AddressList.GetValue(0), IPAddress).ToString
        lip.Text = ipaddress
        lports.Text = rnres
        listener.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lvuser_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvuser.SelectedIndexChanged
        If lvuser.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            frmmsg.Text = lvuser.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I want to ask is how to detect ip and port of applications already installed and displays them in a list view.

anyone can help?

Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do? is there a reason you want this?

Comment: i'm tryng to build chat application on lan :D , Yes

Comment: can't work this way, you will create a port scanner, with bad performance. why don't you use multicast/broadcast to discover other clients, then connect to each other on a specific port?